# Problem raising event from from user control in page code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web

I am trying to process an event from a user control.  I want to test for a condition and read its value in the event handler on the page.  I first tried in VB within the control.

`````````````````````````` VB in User control `````````````````

```
   Public Event EVT(ByRef Status As String)

   Private Sub Process()
    
    Dim sStatus as string

    ' // process code
    '
    '
    '
    If sStatus = sExpected then
        RaiseEvent EVT("Pass")
    Else
        RaiseEvent EVT("Fail")
    End If

    End Sub
```

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
'''''''''''' VB Page code ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''  

       AddHandler foo.TestEvent, AddressOf fooHandler

       Private Sub fooHandler(ByVal Status as string)
          ' process based on value of Status
       End Sub
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

This did not work at all.  I looked at and tried several examples but I don't understand them because of the amount of what looks like superfluous code.  Can someone point me to a simple, preferably VB, example that actually works?

Thank you so much.
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: What exactly is the condition? And what are the values you expect to read?... Can you post your usercontrol code too?

Answer (score 2):

OK, as noted, we want SIMPLE here.

So, let's make up a control. It will be a simple text box, and beside that text box, we have a button.

So, let's create a new user control, and we have this markup so far:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text=""
    style="margin-left:20px"    
    />
```

Now, for code behind, let's have a "Text" property (for the text box), and let’s have a text property for the Button text.

So, we have then this code behind:

```
Public Class BoxButton
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Property Text As String
        Get
            Return tBox.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            tBox.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ButtonText As String
        Get
            If btn.Text = "" Then
                btn.Text = "Button"
            End If
            Return btn.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            btn.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
```

So, note that for ANY public property of the control, it will show up rather nice in the controls property sheet when we drag + drop that user control into a page. And it also will provide intel-sense if you editing the control in markup.

So, then we create a test page, drag + drop the control in from the project explorer.

[image]

So, note closely in the above, how we can fill out the property sheet, since any public property will show up in the property sheet for that control.

So, now when we run above in a test page, we get this:

[image]

And note that even in code behind, we can use those public properties to set, or get the text box value, (Text), or the Button text (ButtonText).

Of course, we now want to add a click event to the user control, and of course like any control we drop into the page, the event has to run in the CURRENT page and work like any other event for such controls.

So, we now will add a click event, and wire up that up correctly.

So, back to our user control. First, we add a button click event to the user control (you can do this by double clicking on the button, or in markup type in onclick= (and IntelliSense will pop a dialog to create a new event). Either way is fine, but keep this trick in mind for the future, since if you drop any button (or user control) buttons into say a grid view, you can't double click on such buttons nested inside of that grid to create the click event, but you can from markup. This was a STUNNING revelation when I learned that trick, and now I often add button click events to say a button in a GridView.

OK, so we add the click event. When we click that button?

Well, it's going to somehow have to bubble back to the page that contained the button.

So, we add a public Event property, and thus have this to our user control:

```
Public Event MyClick As EventHandler

Protected Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    RaiseEvent MyClick(sender, e)

End Sub
```

So, keep in mind that the events now in the markup are required to be prefixed with "On" for events. This is automatic, and is the standard.
So, now, let's code back to the test page, and add a click event. I'm going to do this using the suggested markup:

So, it looks like this:

[image]

So, now if I go to the test page, I will find that an event stub has been created.

It looks like this, and works fine:

```
Protected Sub BoxButton_MyClick()

    Debug.Print($"Text box value ={BoxButton.Text} ")
    Debug.Print($"Button text  value ={BoxButton.ButtonText} ")

    ' so, any old code goes here for this custom control button click
    ' ' event

End Sub
```

Now, eagle eyes will note that the above button click event is not actually 100% correct, since it SHOULD have the sender, and the events parameters. The code stub works, but you could manually edit the code stub and add the 2 missing parameters.

Such as this:

```
Protected Sub BoxButton_MyClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

So, above is a "bare bones" example, and should suffice for most of your needs.

So, I never figured out after many moons, as to why the generated code stub does not include the above 2 parameters in the Sub define. However, they can be left out if you don't need to use the sender and e (event args).

The next step would be to say have the lighting bolt and event tab show up in the property sheet for the custom events. I never figured out how to make that feature work, but in the past, suggesting was that you have to convert the user control to a server control.

Server controls are much like user controls, but they have much more moving parts and setup. While server controls work much like user controls, they can be added to the toolbox, and are deployed as DLLs. However, they are rather painful to write, and thus I recommend the easy user controls. As above shows, user controls are very easy to create, and are a great way to create re-useable components.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you have put into helping me.  My problem is a bit different than   what you show in your solution because I have no static controls -- they are all generated programmatically.  I'm going to keep work at this.  I have expanded my description to better show the code.

Comment: Hum, as a general rule I try to avoid injecting controls into the markup, since then your page behind class code can't resolve as such at compile time.  So, attempting to sink events into injected markup tends to be "difficult" and thus I can't even say this is the result of a user control, but that of injecting any control, and then trying to attach an event to the injected control.  You have to use the pre-render event, but I would avoid injection of controls that need events attached when possbile.